# Locking View Rotation to Landscape for whole app in ios 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, landscape-portrait

I'm new to IOS development, and I'm trying to  write an app for deployment on an ipad. Partly to keep things simple, layout-wise, and because I believe that my users will only use the app in landscape mode, I wish to only allow landscape views, and completely disable portrait views.

I've found a good deal of advice looking around the internet for an answer. Unfortunately, none of it has worked for me. The best answer I've found was to simply to go the target in xcode, and under "deployment info" -> Device Orientation, simply uncheck "Portrait" and "Upside Down". This should, theoretically, solve my issue, but unfortunately, it does not. The view rotates just as normal to portrait mode.

Going to the info tab and setting the Initial Interface Orientation to Landscape (Left) does make the app at least start in Landscape mode, but it does not restrict it only to that mode.

Even adding

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

into my main view doesn't seem to help anything. So I'm somewhat stumped. There must be some setting or something somewhere which is still allowing portrait views. What might this problem be?

Comment: Have you cleaned your project since making that change?  Product -> Clean in the top menu bar.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your *AppName*-Info.plist file, there should be a key titled 'Supported interface orientations'.

You should remove any of the Portrait values in that dictionary and make sure you only have the Landscape values included!

[image]

**Edit:**
In the question-asker's case, their issue involved a piece of code in the AppDelegate that changed the app's supported orientations.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    /* They had the following:
     *     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
     * Which allowed the orientation to rotate to portrait
     */
    
    // This fixed their issue:
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I did that for both Supported interface orientations and Supported interface orientations (iPad), but unfortunately, the problem still persists. Thanks though!

Comment: Super interesting. I've been looking around, and can't see anything that would suggest an ability to override the .plist settings. Could you try adding this to -didFinishLaunching? `application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;`

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I don't think anything seemed to happen. Same old thing - it starts in landscape mode, but will go into portrait mode when rotated in that direction. I put a breakpoint, though, and it definitely was hit.

Comment: Does your app have numerous UIViewControllers? I'm curious about the view lifecycle methods (viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc.). It seems to me that something in your code is telling the app to present in Portrait. Do you have many UINavigation or UITabViewControllers? I see people having issues with those; I'm wondering if your app orientation changes from VC to VC.

Comment: Ah, thanks, this helped me find the answer! In the AppDelegate, which I had not been thinking about, I include the message "supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow", in which I was returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll. Changing that to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLanscape solved the issue.

Comment: Excellent! I'll edit my answer to include that, so people will be able to find it if they had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in General tab in your project

[image]